# How do I open a local HTML file in the Android PreferenceScreen?

Tags: java, android, html, android-intent, preferences

I am trying to open a local HTML file through the PreferenceScreen in Android but failing. I am trying to do it using Intents. This is what I have so far.

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<PreferenceCategory 
    android:title="Help">

    <Preference
        android:title="Help"
        android:summary="Opens the help page">

        <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
                android:data="file:///android_asset/help.html" />

    </Preference>

</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Eclipse says that the error is that "No Activity can be found to handle Intent" which is confusing because if I set the data to http://www.google.com for example it works without any problems. Could someone advise on how I can open this HTML file?

The Html file is stored under src/assets

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PreferenceActivity:

```
Preference prefHelp = findPreference("Help");
prefHelp.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference)
    {
        Intent i = ...;
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, using the click listener on the preference and setting up a simply activity to support the webview worked perfectly.

Comment: I think it was, but I didn't know about the preference click listener ^^